# Html page not opening in node js

Tags: node.js, restify

I've got a button in my `index.html` file which when clicked should open another html page called `index2.html` in the root directory. However, when I click on the button I get a webpage not found option. What am I doing wrong?

**app.js**

```
server.get('/', restify.serveStatic({
 directory: __dirname,
 default: '/index.html'
}));

server.get('/page2', restify.serveStatic({
 directory: __dirname,
 default: 'index2.html'
}));
```

**index.html**

```
<a href="/page2"> <button type="button"> Full Chat history </button>  </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code here..

```
server.get('/page2', restify.serveStatic({
 directory: __dirname,
 default: 'index2.html'
}));
```

Should be

```
server.get('/page2', restify.serveStatic({
 directory:  __dirname,
 file: 'index2.html'
}));
```